# How to add objects to CComboBox

Tags: java, swt, ccombobox

I have declared my CComboBox as follows :

```
     final CCombo combobox= new CCombo(shell, SWT.BORDER);
     combobox.setBounds(30, 22, 88, 21);

     ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
```

I want to add an object of Class myCombo to combobox

```
     while(result.next())
     {
          String ProName=result.getString(1);
          String ProId=result.getString(2);
          myCombo comboItem=new myCombo(ProId,ProName); //OBJECT comboItem
          combobox.addElement(comboItem); //ERROR The method addElement(myCombo)  
                                             is undefined for the type CCombo
      }
```

Error in  combobox.**addElement**(comboItem) .... but addElement() is already defined in CCombo.

This is class myCombo

```
class myCombo{
               private String ProId;
               private String ProName;


               public myCombo(String ProId, String ProName) {
                   this.ProId=ProId;
                   this.ProName=ProName;

               }

               public String getProductName() {
                      return ProName;
                   }

               public String getProductId() {
                      return ProId;
                   }

                   @Override
               public String toString() {
                      return ProName;
               }
        }
```

How to get back the data which is selected.
Showing ERROR as cant

```
combobox.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {



    myCombo item = (myCombo) combo.getItem(getSelectionIndex()) ; //ERROR

                    if (item!=null) {
                       System.out.printf("You've selected Product Name: %s, Product ID: %s%n", 
                             item.getProductName(), item.getProductId());
                    }

            }
        });
```

Comment: If you can, you should use JFace ComboViewer instead of a SWT CCombo direclty

Comment: Swing and SWT are completely different, you should make it clear which you are asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using  [`org.eclipse.swt.custom.CCombo`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fcustom%2FCCombo.html) than it does't have `addElement(Object o)` method.It has `add(String s)` method you have to **override** `toString()`.

```
      myCombo comboItem=new myCombo(ProId,ProName); 
      combobox.add(comboItem.toString())
```

---

***FOR EXAMPLE***

```
           @Override
           public String toString() {
                  return ProId+":"+ProName;
           }
```

TO Fetch Selection,

```
  combo.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            System.out.print("Selected Value-");
            System.out.print(combo.getItem(combo.getSelectionIndex()));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for you help also want to know. How to get back the data. At addSelectionListener

Comment: I cant find how to get the selected data from the combobox and convert into object

Comment: Or you can directly Print `System.out.println(combo.getItem(getSelectionIndex())));`

Comment: The method getSelectionIndex() is undefined for the type new SelectionAdapter(){}  **What should I define in getSelectionIndex() method**